# Stylesheet Bundling with parameters in MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to create stylesheet bundle, but the files within the bundle are to be passed in as a parameter. These files are from a database call, so how do I pass these values into the RegisterBundles function, so this is a normal bundle:

```
public static void RegisterBundles()
{

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/clientstyles")
        .Include("~/css/style.css")
    );
}
```

But I need it to be something like this

```
public static void RegisterBundles(filenamePassedIn)
{

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/clientstyles")
        .Include(filenamePassedIn)
    );
}
```

With the timing of the app starting , how do I get this parameter into this function when it is called at app_start?

Thanks

Comment: I really don't see how is this different than just passing parameters to a normal function

Comment: I guess the point is, is that the the parameter i need to pass into this function will not be available when the function is called. Perhaps someone has done this before and could give a few pointers.

Comment: How come they won't be available? Do the database call and then call the function. I still don't see the problem

Comment: Because the RegisterBundles is called on ApplicationStart:

`protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles();
        }`

Comment: So...? Call the database and retrieve those values before calling that method?

Comment: What are you confused about specifically? I think you may be overthinking this if you're simply wanting to register the bundle once. If your issue it that long after the app has started you wish to switch stylesheets, please clarify that. Totally different requirements.